# While uninstalling python.exe, removing bar closes before it's full so cannot uninstall python

Tags: uninstallation, python-3.10

When I want to remove Python from applications in settings or control panel, I push remove button. Then python.exe opens, before bar is full, It closes and says "**uninstallation was successful**". But ıt remains in computer.

My question is how to completely remove Python from my laptop? Because I guesss I need to install it from beginning.

I were expecting to remove it, I couldn't. I tried to remove from different techniques but It didn't work.